# Can RocksDB change its backup source from local to a remote reliable source? Or does a similar system exist?

Tags: c++, performance, storage, distributed-computing, rocksdb

I need to find or develop a module which can support:
1.support fast data transaction
2.backup all the status to a remote source(HDFS, GFS) asynchronously
3.clear continuous data (such as data less than a timestamp)
4.recover from the remote source

C++，just need sequential reading.

MQ and RocksDB can satisfy my requirements basically, but MQ just support java, RocksDB's random lookup is useless for me(maybe affect performance), at the same time, I didn't know how to change the backup dir to a remote reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is time series data, you can try RocksDB FIFO compaction https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/FIFO-compaction-style
which is like a queue.

For backup/restore, you can have a separate process to move the data from and to remote filesystem.